# How to handle data structure migration in a compositional way in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, serialization, types

I am trying to implement (de)serialization of data structures in Haskell in a way that:

1. Takes care of evolving schema of the data structure,
2. Allows safe reading of past versions if provided some "patching" code exists,
3. Does not need to keep old versions of data type definition around (as is the case with [safecopy](https://github.com/acid-state/safecopy/)

I have implemented this mechanism in the past in a way that I find unsatisfying: There is much repetition in the code as it needs to traverse whole structure even if only a leaf changes, and the code to handle various versions is not composable.

What I am looking for is something that would work like a stream of patches in a VCS: At each version change, I need only to write the code to handle the specific change (e.g. some field is transformed from `Text` to `Int`, there is a new field, some field is deleted...) and given some serialized chunk of bytes at a known version, the `load` function applies all patches to retrieve a valid data structure.

I have tried to write some code along those lines but cannot get something that's composable in the way I am looking for (and I did not even tackled the issue of sum types...). Here is my attempt:

```
data Versioned (v :: Nat) a where
  (:$:) ::             (a -> b) -> Versioned v a -> Versioned v b
  (:*:) :: Versioned v (a -> b) -> Versioned v a -> Versioned v b
  Atom  :: Get a                                 -> Versioned v a
  Cast  :: Versioned v' a                        -> Versioned v a
```

The idea was to reify an applicative structure in such a way it becomes possible to apply minimal changes.

This seems only doable using some form of `Generic` deserialization mechanism: Deserialize the bytes to a generic form then apply a chain of transformator to reach a shape that satisfies current.

Any hint towards a solution would be most helpful.

**2017-02-13**

My problem can be split in two sub-problems:

1. How to ensure statically there exist deserialization functions for each version, up to some (statically) known version?
2. How to handle migration of data structure in a safe and minimally invasive way?

Problem 1. yields the following (non compiling code):

```
  -- | A class instantiating a serializer/deserializer for some version
  class Versionable (v :: Nat) a where
    reader :: Proxy v -> Get a
    writer :: Proxy v -> a -> Put

  -- | Current version is a "global" constraint
  type family CurrentVersion :: Nat

  class VersionUpTo (v :: Nat) a

  instance (Versionable 1 a) => VersionUpTo 1 a
  instance (Versionable v  a, VersionUpTo (v - 1) a) => VersionUpTo v a

  load :: (VersionUpTo CurrentVersion a) => ByteString -> Either String [a]
  load = runGet loadGetter
    where
      loadGetter = sequence $ repeat $ do
        v <- getInt32be
        case v of
          1 -> reader (Proxy :: Proxy 1)
          2 -> reader (Proxy :: Proxy 2)
          3 -> reader (Proxy :: Proxy 3)
```

The problem is, of course, the value of `v` to dispatch on depends on `CurrentVersion a`, which raises the following issue:

1. How to write a generic `load` function that will read the version from underlying byte stream and dispatch to the correct reader function, without resorting to explicitly enumerate all cases?

Even if `CurrentVersion` is not statically at call site of `load`, it is not known at definition site hence it is not possible to enumerate all valid cases. It seems the only option would be to somehow generate the cases using TH...

Problem 2. is orthogonal to 1. Here the problem is that a data structure typed `T` evolves over time but we need to take care of old representations: We should be able to deserialize any version `v` of `T` up to the `CurrentVersion`. This is easily done by defining a `Versionable n T` for each target version, but this introduces a lot of redundancy given the changes between versions `n` and `n+1` are usually limited to one part of the structure.

I think that the metaphor of a stream of patches does not work because it actually goes backward: The starting point is the current data structure and we need to adapt the past representations to the current version. Here are 3 versions of the same object:

```
 instance Versionable 1 Obj3 where
   reader _ = doGet $ Obj3 :$: (fromInt :$: getint) :*: (fromText :$: Atom get)

 instance Versionable 2 Obj3 where
   reader _ = doGet $ Obj3 :$: Atom get :*: (fromText :$: Atom get)

 instance Versionable 3 Obj3 where
    reader _          = doGet $ Obj3 :$: Atom get :*: getf2 F2
    writer _ Obj3{..} = put f31 >> put f32
```

There is some regularity as we see each past version is an adaptation of the current version.

Hence the idea of representing `reader` as a reified `Applicative` (or maybe `Monad`ic) functor to which can be applied surgical updates to cope with older versions. But then I am stuck with how to select some node deep in the tree of current deserialisers to apply some change in a typesafe way...

**2017-02-13**

Point 2. above seems to lead to nothing but convoluted code, involving a lot of type-level wizardry for a minor benefit. Consider the aforementioned 3 versions of `Obj3`, ideally I would like to find a way to write:

```
 geto3 = Obj3 :$: Atom get :*: getf2 F2

 instance Versionable 2 Obj3 where
   reader _ = doGet $ _replaceAt (0,1) (fromText :$: Atom get) get03

 instance Versionable 3 Obj3 where
    reader _          = doGet $ get03
    writer _ Obj3{..} = put f31 >> put f32
```

where `_replaceAt :: (Int, Int) -> Versioned a -> Versioned b -> Versioned b` means that we want to replace some subtree at index `(x,y)` in the deserializer for `b`, whose type is `Versioned a`, with the second argument. It seems doable to express that in type-safe way but this requires exposing the structure of `Obj3` as a type `T` in `Versioned T`.

Comment: This is a pretty neat idea, but I don't think I've fully understood the motivation. Why not just have functions that translate from one version to the next (_not_ in the complex `Versioned` format)? Otherwise, I recommend you look at how `Generic` is defined. You might even want to use it instead since you get conversion to and from datatypes for free with `DeriveGeneric`.

Comment: The motivation for having an explicit "generic" form to manipulate is to remove a lot of boilerplate. Say I have a datatype  `T` which is a record with 10 fields: Each time I change one of those fields, I need to either 1/ store an old version of `T` which is 90% identical to the previous version, or 2/ write a deserialisation function that is 90% identical to the previous, save for one of the fields. Hence the idea of using "patches" to represent the various versions...

Comment: What you are describing sounds like a use case for storing your data in JSON and then having a more flexible deserializer. Having mucked around with `Generic`, I can tell you it is at once brilliant and very tough to get to work properly - hardly something you would want to have to go through every time you tweak your model.

Comment: @insitu If datatype `T` changes, could you not simply change the code for that type? This amounts to changing code for a single field, if a single field has changed. If you are keeping the old function `f :: T -> A` when `T` changes to `T'` you need to keep the `T` type as well (but this contradicts your third point) for `f` to remain well-typed after the change. `f` must have a type like `GenericRep T -> A` to continue working if you change `T`; but the type must not actually mention `T`, only the generic representation of `T`. Depending on your use case, this may be simple or impossible.

Comment: @alec I used to use JSON for storing data, which has its advantages (legibility in plain text) and disadvantages (very redundant information). I agree it is easier to work with than `Generic` or byte-level data, but I think what I am looking for is somehow independent of the underlying representation.

Comment: @user2407038 actually no, because if `T` changes, I still have to take care of old versions of `T` which have been stored before I introduce the change. The upside is that they are stored in a serialized form, so I can tweak the deserialization process to get a (new) `T` from an old version. safecopy works by keep old definitions of `T` around, which obviously works well and allows defining functions like `migrate : T@v1 -> T@v2` very easily, but imagine 1 year down the road, if I have to maintain 20 versions of T...