# How to generically replace some part of a Haskell data structure?

Tags: haskell, generics, types, type-level-computation

This post is a follow-up to a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179682/how-to-handle-data-structure-migration-in-a-compositional-way-in-haskell)...

I am trying to handle the sub-problem of updating a structure in a generic way, with the ultimate goal of being able to write something like that:

```
 g = graft idx "foo" obj
   where
     idx = Proxy :: Proxy '[1,0]
     obj = Ap Obj3 (Ap F1 ((12 :: Int):-: ("bar" :: Text)) :-: Ap F2 ("baz" :: Text))
```

Here are some clarifications upon the intended "semantics" of `graft`:

1. `obj` is meant to be a multiway tree representing some data structure in a generic way. It is expected to be constructed with 2 elements: Nested pairs represent (horizontal) sequences of nodes, `Ap f a` represents suspended application of some function `f` to some argument `a`, where `a` can be a sequence of arguments as mentioned,
2. Each "instance" of `obj` has a type which mimics the tree structure of the values, but of course with types instead of values as nodes,
3. `idx` represents a *path* in the multiway tree `obj` as a sequence of indices to reach some point in the tree
4. `graft` then replaces the element from `obj` at `path` with some other value (in the case of the example, `"foo"`). The idea is that `graft` works recursively from the root of the tree, following each segment of `path` until it finds the node and replaces the value with `a`, all in a type-safe way: The replacement value `a` should have the same type than the node at `path` in the grafted tree.

In the case of the given example, when `g` is evaluated, it should yield the following structure:

```
 obj = Ap Obj3 (Ap F1 (12 :-: "bar") :-: Ap F2 "foo")
```

I have tried to define the `Graft` typeclass to handle traversing a data structure given some path:

```
 class Graft a path b where
   graft :: path -> a -> b -> b
```

then instances are defined using type-level lists of `Nat`s:

```
 type a :-: b = (a, b)
 infixr 5 :-:

 pattern (:-:) :: a -> b -> (a ,b)
 pattern a :-: b = (a ,b)

 instance Graft a (Proxy '[0]) (a :-: b) where
   graft _ a (_ :-: b) = a :-: b

 instance Graft a (Proxy '[]) a where
   graft _ a _ = a
```

Things go awry when I try to apply `graft` recursively. The following instance do not compile

```
 instance (Graft a (Proxy k) b) => Graft a (Proxy (0 ': k)) (b :-: c) where
   graft _ a (b :-: c) = graft p a b :-: c
     where
       p = Proxy :: Proxy k
```

yielding the message:

```
  error:
      • Could not deduce (Graft a (Proxy k4) b)
          arising from a use of ‘graft’
        from the context: Graft a (Proxy k) b
          bound by the instance declaration
          at /Users/arnaud/projects/gorillaspace/gorilla-space/hevents/.stack-work/intero/intero398uMH.hs:65:10-68
        The type variable ‘k4’ is ambiguous
        Relevant bindings include
          b :: b
            (bound at /Users/arnaud/projects/gorillaspace/gorilla-space/hevents/.stack-work/intero/intero398uMH.hs:66:14)
          a :: a
            (bound at /Users/arnaud/projects/gorillaspace/gorilla-space/hevents/.stack-work/intero/intero398uMH.hs:66:11)
          graft :: Proxy (0 : k) -> a -> b :-: c -> b :-: c
            (bound at /Users/arnaud/projects/gorillaspace/gorilla-space/hevents/.stack-work/intero/intero398uMH.hs:66:3)
      • In the first argument of ‘(:-:)’, namely ‘graft p a b’
        In the expression: graft p a b :-: c
        In an equation for ‘graft’:
            graft _ a (b :-: c)
              = graft p a b :-: c
              where
                  p = Proxy :: Proxy k
```

The following instances which complete the traversals do not compile either, yielding the same kind of error:

```
 instance (Graft a (Proxy (n-1 : k)) c) => Graft a (Proxy (n ': k)) (b :-: c) where
   graft _ a (b :-: c) = b :-:  graft p a c
     where
       p = Proxy :: Proxy (n-1 : k)

 instance (Graft a (Proxy k) b) => Graft a (Proxy (0 ': k)) (Ap f b c) where
   graft _ a (Ap f b) = Ap f (graft p a b)
     where
       p = Proxy :: Proxy k
```

So it seems the destructured type-level variables `k` is not "visible" in the recursive call to `graft`, a problem which I don't know how to fix.

Comment: 1. `ScopedTypeVariables` 2. One example doesn't define a semantics.

Comment: Thanks for 1. I am surprised the compiler did not warned me about that (I thought I had it defined at the package level, which is not the case), but I know understand I did not understand this flag!

Comment: @user2407038 I agree with 2. but it the semantics seems to me pretty clear: `graft` is used to update some element in a tree structure in a "generic" way, e.g. without having to define explicit update functions (or lenses). As I mention at the beginning of this question, the underlying motivation is to handle migration of getters for data structures in a way that ensures all previous versions are taken care of and produce the correct data.

Comment: GHC could not possibly know the programmers intent, so it couldn't possibly know that you need ScopedTypeVariables, in particular since enabling this extension may cause type correct code to no longer type check. Your semantics are stated entirely in terms of what you abstractly hope to achieve, but there is a huge gulf between abstract semantics and concrete semantics. It is entirely unclear what `obj` and `idx` are meant to represent, and what part of your code represents the 'history of the type', or even how to represent any particular type, at least to me.

Comment: As already said: It appears I did not understand `ScopedTypeVariables` and I owe you this enlightenment, hence my remark which should be understood sequentially: First I read your comment, which fixes my issue. Then I am surprised the compiler did not warn me about this missing extension. Finally, I understand this extension did not mean what I initially thought it meant which caused my initial surprise... Hope this clarifies 1st point.

Comment: @user2407038 Thanks for your Socratic questions which give me the incentive to try to clarify my thoughts and goal

Comment: I think I understand now - `Ap F1 ((12 :: Int):-: ("bar" :: Text))` is supposed to represent something like `data F1 = F1 Int Text`. I don't think you need to represent the actual value of the data at the type level, just the shape of it. (trying to do this will make your code much more complex and also severely restrict what you can do). Furthermore, there is no way for you to produce the type `"foo"` from the value `"foo"` (at best you can get an existentially quantified Symbol, but this isn't a real issue - the "foo" arg could just be a type level arg).

Comment: Most importantly, your 2nd point is not even true! `obj = Ap Obj3 (Ap F1 ((12 :: Int):-: ("bar" :: Text)) :-: Ap F2 ("baz" :: Text))` is a value, not a type, so you do not have "types instead of values as nodes". (this is the advantage of clearly stating the semantics - without such a statement it's not possible to tell if you have made a mistake in implementation or I simply don't understand what you want to do)

Comment: And finally, it seems like you are just trying to recreating lenses, but without referring to the actual type in the implementation of the lens, instead to the 'representation' of the type (for which you are probably best off using some existing generic mechanism instead of trying to roll your own). Why do lenses not satisfy your requirements? You can still use `Nat` indices to denote the 'position' in the type, but the underlying semantics seems to me to be just that of lenses.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135790/discussion-between-insitu-and-user2407038).